# Could a switch statement that switches resources be more generic?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, resources

I am working on a kiosk application that has a button to choose a language.

The button after that has a picture of the languages flag and it's name. Right now I am using a switch statement to set the image, but I would like to have it more generic so when adding languages I wouldn't have to change code everywhere. I am getting the image from my apps resources, and I would like to keep it that way.

The only way I can think of would be by retrieving the images from files and naming them according to the language string they are for. The language string is in this format "en-US". Also the language string is declared in a function before this one is called.

```
private void SetLanguageButton()
        {
            switch (language)
            {
                case "en-US":
                    buttonLanguage.Image = Properties.Resources.en_US;
                    break;

                case "hu-HU":
                    buttonLanguage.Image = Properties.Resources.hu_HU;
                    break;

                case "sk-SK":
                    buttonLanguage.Image = Properties.Resources.sk_SK;
                    break;
            }
            buttonLanguage.Text = resourceManager.GetString("languageName", cultureInfo);
        }
```

Comment: _The only way I can think of_ Your "way" sounds good to me. So what are you asking? Are you asking if your way is a good way? Or are you asking if there's a different, better way?

Comment: I am asking if there is a generalized way. This way is quite bad because it is hard coded. And If you meant my file way I would like to do it using resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have cultural-ized resources, you can get data as following

```cs
buttonLanguage.Image = 
    (Icon)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("langicon", cultureInfo);
buttonLanguage.Text = 
    Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("langname", cultureInfo);
```

Comment: It says 'Cannot implicitly convert Object to System.Drawing.Image'

Comment: @PSONGDALI what about this `= (Icon)ResourceManager.GetObject(....)`... i.e. explicitely

Comment: I used this code buttonLanguage.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(language.Replace("-", "_"), cultureInfo);

Comment: Good. Enjoy. here is reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @PSONGDALI Actually I wasn't sure initially. I thought you have all icons in 1 file. Then naming convention can be used. But if you have one resource file per culture - you can just use the posted code